# What is the most elegant way to make this kind of string array change?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I have an array of string like:

```
var myStrArr=['book-in-my-house',
              'chair-in-my-house',
              'bed-in-my-house',
              'TV-in-my-house'];
```

I would like to change ***myStrArr*** to ***herStrArr*** like:

```
var herStrArr=['book-in-her-house',
              'chair-in-her-house',
              'bed-in-her-house',
              'TV-in-her-house'];
```

As you saw above, change every "`my`" to "`her`" in each string.
What is the most elegant way to make this change in JavaScript?

Comment: how about remove all 'my' to construct strArr?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No other way than looping through. As you noted in your tags that you are using jQuery, you can use jQuery's `$.map` to assist. It's not technically the most elegant solution, but one of the simplest and shortest:

```
var herStrArr = $.map(myStrArr, function(str) {
    return str.replace('-my-', '-her-');
});
```

Comment: +1, but careful with the use of keywords as variable names ;)

Comment: @Box9, true, oversight on my part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery `$.each` function.

```
var myStrArr=['book-in-my-house',
              'chair-in-my-house',
              'bed-in-my-house',
              'TV-in-my-house'];

$.each(myStrArr,function(i){ myStrArr[i] = myStrArr[i].replace('-my-','-her-');})
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xx5XM/

Comment: Better. Not sure how pointing out a fundamental flaw in your code makes me a "puritan", but there we go.

Answer (score 0):

You don't *have* to use a loop - if you can choose a character guaranteed not to be contained in any string. For example, with `"|"` you can do:

```
var herStrArr = myStrArr.join("|").replace(/\bmy\b/gi, "her").split("|");
```

---

To *remove* the word "my", I assume you mean that you want:

```
book-in-my-house => book-in-house
```

If so, then:

```
var strArr = myStrArr.join("|").replace(/-my\b/gi, "").split("|");
```

Answer (score 0):

Store `['book', 'chair', 'bed', 'TV']` instead, then you don't have to do anything.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question even slightly. And you had the cheek to downvote a perfectly good (if terse) answer. I won't downvote you back, as im not that petty.

Comment: @Jamiec: It completely answers the question. This is the most elegant way to achieve the OP's goal: he should remove all that silly data redundancy. And I told you why I downvoted you; I don't see how pointing out a serious flaw in your answer is "cheeky". This will be my last comment on the issue.

Comment: @Jamiec, I think this answer has merit, but the way it's phrased opens it to misinterpretation. By storing only the parts of the string that differ, you can easily append `'my'`, `'her'`, or whatever else you wish.

Comment: It is unlikely that the user is actually trying to take an array that he defines explicitly and change it once. That would be pointless, of course he could just have stored the final values in the first place. Almost certainly he does not have direct control over the source of the data because it's in a database or some other dynamic source. This does not answer the question, and actually undermines the value of good question writing (to boil a problem down to its essence). You're just saying "if you didn't have a problem then you wouldn't have a problem."

Comment: @jamietre - spot on. This is a non-answer. The OP clearly hasnt described the exact problem, but the essence of it.

Comment: Regardless, this is the best way to store such data, applying the suffixes as required when extracting the data from within the array.